# Does Google Analytics indicates object tag

Tags: pdf, google-analytics, object-tag

on my website I will include some PDF-files via object tag like in the example below. Does Google Analytics indicates the pdf files inside the object tag. So is it possible that I can find the pdf file when I search for it in Google. Or is there a more common way to do that?

```
  <object data="object.pdf" type="application/pdf" style="width:100%;height:300px">
   <a href="object.pdf">PDF laden</a>
  </object>
```

Comment: I think your problem is more about SEO, or page indexing not about Google Analytics. But answering your question: yes Google will index file embeded in this way.

Comment: Is your question that you can find the PDF download in Google Analytics? Or like Jacek pointed out, if Google Search might find it?

Comment: My question was like Jacek pointed out. I only want to know if I might find the PDF file with Google Search. I was not really sure if Google bot indicates the object tag with the link to PDF file.